# Why does R t.test()'s confidence interval shift slightly w.r.t. alternative hypothesis?

Tags: r, t-test, excel

So I've noticed something extremely confusing about t.test, which is that the confidence interval it provides w.r.t a two-sided alt hypothesis seems to be inconsistent with what it provides for a one-sided test, my own CI function & excel's `CONFIDENCE()` (which are consistent with each other). In addition it appears to be inconsistent with my own two-tailed z test function, and all of these inconsistencies are pretty small (but bigger than floating point error)!

Here is my example:
t.test---

```
sample = c(38, 30, 41, 28, 31)
t.test(sample) # CI = 26.65334, 40.54666

t.test(sample, alternative = 'less') # CI = -Inf, 38.93388
t.test(sample, alternative = 'greater') # CI = 28.26612,  Inf`
```

My own CI---

```
# tested 10/5/19
# xbar = sample mean, s = sample sigma, n = sample size
mean_conf_interval <- function(xbar, s, n, conf_lvl=0.95) {
  z_a2 <- qnorm((1-conf_lvl)/2, lower.tail=F)
  err_margin <- z_a2*s/sqrt(n)
  return(c(xbar-err_margin, xbar+err_margin))
}

mean_conf_interval(mean(sample),sd(sample),length(sample))
# CI = 28.26612,  38.93388
```

excel--- (rough translation to pseudo code)

```
E276:E280 = 38, 30, 41, 28, 31 # same sample as before
B277 = CONFIDENCE(0.05,  STDEV(E276:E280), COUNT(E276:E280)) # error margin
B278=AVERAGE(E276:E280) # xbar
# CI = B278-B277, B278+B277 = 28.69617167,  38.50382833
```

For the sake of brevity I won't go into comparison with my own two-sided-z-test function unless necessary. But what's going on? This is so strange that it actually looks like a bug...

Comment: Well, `t.test` uses the $t$-quantile instead of your function which uses the normal quantile. In large samples, the differences are negligible but in your example, the $t$-quantile is $2.776$ whereas the normal quantile is $1.96$. Add `qt((1-conf_lvl)/2, df = n - 1, lower.tail=FALSE)` to your function and the results are identical.

Comment: I *strongly* disagree with the off-topic vote. While this obviously involves R and code, the answer is inherently a statistical one, relating to the differences between the Z and T distributions.

Comment: I agree; *code* doesn't make it off topic, *as long as it requires statistical expertise to understand or answer*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the standard normal distribution to calculate the 0.975 quantile as 1.96. You should be using the $t_{n-1}$ distribution, which will give a value somewhat larger than 1.96.

Try `z_a2 <- qt((1-conf_lvl)/2,n-1,lower.tail=F)` in your function and see what you get.

**Edit**: I have run the following code, getting the same confidence interval that I have in my comment.

```
mean_conf_interval <- function(xbar, s, n, conf_lvl=0.95) {
  z_a2 <- qnorm((1-conf_lvl)/2, lower.tail=F)
  err_margin <- z_a2*s/sqrt(n)
  return(c(xbar-err_margin, xbar+err_margin))
}

sample <- c(38, 30, 41, 28, 31)
xbar <- mean(sample)
s <- sd(sample)
n <- length(sample)
mean_conf_interval(xbar,s,n)
```

Comment: So then is only the t-quantile CI correct? Also could you please address why t.test's finite one-sided CI boundaries appear to also use norm-quantiles instead of t-quantiles?

Comment: You use the t-test to account for the fact that you're estimating the variance. For the one-sided intervals, I am not getting the numbers that you are getting. My confidence interval is narrower: $( 28.69617   ,38.50383   )$.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful to know.
But no those are the numbers that I get for one-sided intervals (please recheck my post)! That's my point; I don't understand why I get those for one-sided intervals (apparently using norm-quantile) but the wider one (using t-quantile) for two-sided. And to reiterate these are both from the t.test() function.

Comment: @profPlum Please post your verbatim R code. I do not get the confidence interval that you get.

Comment: I did and I just reran it to double check, the *verbatim* R code is in the first code-box of my post (not counting the inline one).

Comment: I should mention however that I never get this narrower interval all in one piece, since they are one-sided tests one side is always infinity. If you look at the comments you'll see what I get exactly.

Comment: @profPlum What happens if you run my code?

Comment: works! cool
 I still don't understand why one-sided t.test uses norm quantiles but whatever I'll give it to you because you answered most of my question